# Accessing Flask application context within python-socketio Client()'s event handler

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I am trying to access Flask application context inside the `python-socketio`'s event handler `on_tick()`, and I am presented with error -

```
(...)
 File "H:\Python\autotrader2\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 316, in __get__
    obj = instance._get_current_object()  # type: ignore[misc]
  File "H:\Python\autotrader2\venv\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 513, in _get_current_object
    raise RuntimeError(unbound_message) from None
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
the current application. To solve this, set up an application context
with app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.
```

Tried to extract a self sufficient miniature version of a larger program -

```
import socketio
from flask import current_app

class MySocketIOClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sio = socketio.Client()
        self.sio.connect("https://feeds.sio.server",
                         headers={"User-Agent": "python-socketio[client]/socket"},
                         auth={"user": "user_id", "token": "session_token"},
                         transports="websocket")

    def execute(self):
        # with current_app.app_context():  # Does not work
        with current_app.test_request_context('/'):  # Does not work
            self.sio.on('update', self.on_tick)
            # self.sio.wait()  # Does not work either

    def on_tick(self, tick):
        print(tick)
        # Error: working outside application context
        print("APP_TIMEZONE={}".format(current_app.config.get('APP_TIMEZONE')))  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MySocketIOClient().execute()
```

How to access Flask's application context (or request context) in the event handler?

Comment: read [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/appcontext/)

Answer (score 0):

`current_app` only works when there is already an app context installed, so it is not useful in your case.

For this you need to import your application instance:

```py
from x import app

class MySocketIOClient:
    # ...

    def on_tick(self, tick):
        print("APP_TIMEZONE={}".format(app.config.get('APP_TIMEZONE')))
```

Here I'm using `x` as a placeholder for the module that has your Flask application instance.

Comment: I'm using app factory, so the app instance is not available. Is there a way to push app context?

Comment: And the issue is not only within `MySocketIOClient` class. The methods from different modules that are called within `on_tick()` use `current_app`. So I guess, I cannot import `app` everywhere else too.

Comment: But you understand what I'm saying, right? The use of `current_app` requires an app context to be pushed in advance. `current_app` returns the application from the pushed app context. If there is no app or request context then `current_app` cannot be used and you need a different mechanism to obtain the Flask app.

Comment: As for how to obtain the app when there is no app context and you have an app factory, you should consider redesigning your app so that you do have an app that you can import. Create the app explicitly by calling your app factory function, for example, and then you have something you can import. Or else move the configuration data that you need to access to some other global instead of the flask app instance.